# Promise which inludes another async await promise - how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I need to make two post requests in succession. There is an async "post form" function which starts the request with the "await" keyword and the result is handled in the "then" block.

I try to do this post request by awaiting a promise, wherein I call the above mentioned async function. The problem is that it doesn't seem that the promise can be resolved inside the functions `"then"` block.

I have some example code to show the issue (look at `start()` function where it starts). See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/pagcsf4w)

```
//Returns a promise. It contains another async-await promise
function mainFunction() {

  return new Promise( () => {           //<-- this never resolves

       async function postForm(){

          //(Post a form)
         await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('resolved');
              }, 2000);

          }).then( response => {    // <-- how to resolve the first promise inside here?

               console.log('promise 2 response: ',response) 

               //Try to resolve the 1st promise (doesn't work)
               new Promise( (resolve,reject) => resolve('promise 1 resolved') );

          }).catch( error => {
              console.log(error)
          }) 
      }
      postForm();

  })

}

//Make two posts in succession
async function start(){ 

  //Post 1 - (never resolves)
  await mainFunction().then( response => {

        //(Next: make post request 2)

  }).catch( error => {
      console.log(error)
  })
}

start();
```

How can I resolve the first promise, or isn't it possible? Is there some other solution?
The idea is to make another post request when the first one is resolved.

Comment: well there are many mistakes here, thats not how promises / async await works

Comment: It is absolutely unsurprising that the Promise returned by `mainFunction()` never resolves. There's no attempt to resolve it. If the purpose of `mainFunction()` is to simulate some asynchronous process, then simply write `function mainFunction() {
 return Promise.resolve();
}`.

Comment: `async/await` is an alternative syntax to `.then()`. Avoid mixing the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use promises then you work with `.then()` and `.catch()` if you work with `async/ await` then you dont use `.then()` and `.catch()` because async / await is syntatic sugar so that we dont need to nest our responses over and over.

If you want to make 2 post request for example with `axios` or `fetch` then you can simply use `async / await` because they return an promise.

```
async function requests(){
   //await makes the request wait till it gets some response
   const response1 = await axios.post("url", {data});
   const response2 = await axios.post("url2", {data});

}
```

Comment: How do I handle error responses (like 500 server error) with this code?
I was using an already existing function which posts the form and handles result in "then". So I modified that and made it async. Maybe I need to change that altogether, but it may have consequenses because it is being called in other cases where I don't need to do things in this successive way.

Comment: here is more info https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling

Comment: It seems I can use a try catch to deal with them. So that might work..